# Proving that $\sum_p\frac{1}{p+1}$ diverges

Tags: prime-numbers, divergent-series

How does one prove
$$\sum_{p\in\Bbb P}\frac1{p+1}=\infty.$$

Where $\Bbb P$ denotes the set of prime numbers.

---

I have attempted forming an inequality by playing around with Euler's work on the reciprocals of primes. Robjohn showed me an inequality in chat that I do not understand and I was wondering if there was another way to do this. The work I have done is inconclusive and is nothing more than stating $$\sum_{p\in\Bbb P}\frac1p\ge\sum_{p\in\Bbb P}\frac1{p+1}$$

Comment: Perhaps you wanted your question's title's last word to be "diverges" instead...?

Comment: so any p is a prime number? is that what you meant an element of P?

Comment: $\sum_{p\in \mathbb P} \frac 1 p = \frac 1 {2} +\sum_{p \gt 2}\frac 1{p} \lt \frac 1 2 + \sum_{p\in \mathbb P} \frac 1 {1+p}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum \frac{1}{p+p} < \sum \frac{1}{p+1} \implies \frac{1}{2} \sum \frac{1}{p} < \sum \frac{1}{p+1}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use that $p+1$ is less than the next prime after $p$ except when $p=2$. So you can use a comparison, and drop the first term, which doesn't affect convergence/ divergence.

Comment: Is it possible to be more rigorous when dropping the first term?

Comment: @Alizter $\sum_{p\in \mathbb P} \frac 1 p = \frac 1 {2} +\sum_{p \gt 2}\frac 1{p} \lt \frac 1 2 + \sum_{p\in \mathbb P} \frac 1 {1+p}$ with appropriate top limits for the sum, which go to infinity.